# Installation of Red5 Server

Tags: linux, maven, ant, vps, red5

I am trying to install Red5 server on my dedicated VPS server. My server is Ubuntu 12.04. I'm doing my installation over SSH in Terminal on Mac. I have Java 7 JDK and JRE installed.

I am doing installation over Maven because I realised that newer versions of Red5 do not support installation over Apache Ant and Ivy. If I try like that (over ant) in moment of installation where I need to execute prepare ant and `ant dist`, I have build.xml file not find message.

My server:

- Apache Maven 3.0.4
- Maven home: /usr/share/maven
- Java version: 1.7.0_80, vendor: Oracle Corporation
- Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre
- Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: ANSI_X3.4-1968
- OS name: "linux", version: "3.1.9-vs2.3.2.5vs2.3.2.5+", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

Steps which I am doing:

```
1. cd /usr/src

2. wget https://github.com/Red5/red5-server/archive/v1.0.5-RELEASE.zip

3. unzip v1.0.5-RELEASE.zip 

4. mv  v1.0.5-RELEASE /usr/local/ 

5. cd  v1.0.5-RELEASE 

6. mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true install
```

After, I enter:

```
mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true install
```

Installation starts and after awhile I have `Build failed` message. This is the error with I get:

> Failed to execute goal on project red5-server: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project org.red5:red5-server:jar:1.0.5-RELEASE:
>   Failure to find org:jaudiotagger:jar:2.0.4-SNAPSHOT in
>   http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots was cached
>   in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the
>   update interval of sonatype-snapshots has elapsed or updates are
>   forced

Apparently there is an issue with the pom.xml file. How can I solve this? Do you have some other way installing Red5 and eventually configure it for video streaming?

Answer (score 0):

Installing Red5 Server and installing artifacts with Maven are two entirely different things in this case. Lets cover maven first; when you execute the install goal with maven, you are telling it to publish your artifacts to your local .m2 repository, this would not be what I assume you want, unless you're developing the code in Red5 itself. To install Red5 Server, simply unzip the archive you pulled with wget and run red5.sh or red5.bat (depending on your os) and that's it. The archive is the assemble server and all its parts.